# How to get patterns widgets to work in an iframe overlay

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I have some "classic" tiles on a Plone 4.3.6 site, which contain a `richtext` field and two `RelationChoice` fields using `plone.formwidget.contenttree` widgets.
I have installed `plone.app.widgets 1.8.0` (along with p.a.contenttypes), and I can't get the new TinyMCE and the new `relateditems` pattern widget to work properly.  If I load the tile view URL directly (at the `@@edit-tile/....` URL), the widgets actually show up and work properly.  But in the iframe/overlay, they don't.

The `prep-overlay` looks like this:

```
  jQuery('.tile-editable').each(function () {
      jQuery(this).find('a.tile-edit-link, a.tile-delete-link').
          prepOverlay({
          subtype: 'iframe',
          config: {
              onLoad: function (e) {
                jQuery('body').addClass('noscroll');
                return true;
              },
              onClose: function() {
                jQuery('body').removeClass('noscroll');
                location.reload();
              }
          }
      });
  });
```

The iframe loads `++resource++plone.app.widgets.js` in the header, and the fields are given the `pat-relateditems` and `pat-tinymce` classes as expected.  But the `init` method inside the `relateditems` pattern is never called.  I suppose the iframe DOM is not parsed for patterns, but I don't know where to look for the cause of this.
FWIW, there is an error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (){return eb}
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
```

in plone.app.widgets.js:166, but I don't know where that's coming from, or if it matters.

Are there any tricks to getting mockup widgets to work in an ifram overlay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reinitialise all patterns you can do:

```
var registry = require("pat-registry");
registry.scan(SELECTOR);  // document or iframe or wherever you want to rescan all patterns.
```

IMHO you could do this on the onLoad method.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I'm still not sure whether the patterns are reinitialized, or not.  For the SELECTOR in registry.scan I've used registry.scan($('.overlay-iframe').contents().find('body')[0]);  I tried both with the [0] and without.

Comment: It appears it's getting called after the iframe is created, but before any content is loaded.  It just has an empty head and body.

Comment: Ok, I've moved your suggested code to the head of the iframe content, and there I can just use 'document' in my selector.  Now I can finally get the relateditems pattern to work.  The tinymce also almost works, it just throws a strange error, but seems to load, anyway.